# HTML %TEMPLATE% is returning the wrong string to server

Tags: html, templates, esp32

I have a history of writing HTML code of almost 1 day and I have a problem I don't understand. It has to do with filling a template. The template name is in %% but what the server is getting is some random piece of the HTML code instead of the template name.
My original code that was working looks like this:

```
      <p>Roof State <span id="roofIsOpen">%roofIsOpen%</span>
       <br>Roof Safe <span id="roofIsSafe">%roofIsSafe%</span>
       <br>LCD <span id="isDark">%isDark%</span></p>
```

The Server was getting the string "roofIsOpen" and the like and then replacing the field `%roofIsOpen%` with the string my ESP32 code supplied.

I tried to get fancy and format the results in 2 columns. The code looks like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
  

      .column {
        float: left;
        width: 15%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      /* Clear floats after the columns */
      
      .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body style="font-family:sans-serif;" text="5d6d7e" bgcolor="18191a">
      <h2 style="color: #8e44ad"><strong>Thermal Sky Monitor</strong></h2>
      <h3 style="color: #3399ff">ROOF CONTROLLER</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <p> Roof State
            <br>Roof Safe
            <br>LCD
            <br>Last Get
            <br>ASCOM Connected
            <br>Last Image Refresh
            <br>RCCI Get </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <p> <span id="roofIsOpen">%roofIsOpen%</span>
            <br><span id="roofIsSafe">%roofIsSafe%</span>
            <br><span id="isDark">%isDark%</span>
            <br><span id="LastGET">%LastGET%</span>
            <br><span id="ASCOMConnected">%ASCOMConnected%</span>
            <br><span id="RoofDistance">%RoofDistance%</span>
            <br><span id="lastReadMLX90640Image">%lastReadMLX90640Image%</span>
            <br><span id="RCCIGet">%RCCIGet%</span> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What the Server is getting for the first template is "

```
    ;
        padding: 10px;

  }
  /* Cl"
```

For the second template it is getting `"</span> <br><span id="ro"`

Given my vast experience of nearly a whole day of doing this can anybody tell be what I did wrong?

Comment: I you look at the snippet you say the server is getting for the first template, you see `; padding: 10px`, which happens to be the part that comes immediately after `width: 15%`, in your source, meaning the `%` character is being interpreted as part of your template variable. Either try to escape this character (`\%` might work, not sure what template engine you use) or see if there is a setting to change the character used for the template with something else (like `{roofIsOpen}`).

Comment: Thanks. I think you hit on it. The template is processed in a ESP32 library so I can't change it but I can change it to something like 400px instead of 15%